# Can a 2-class classifier output the likelihood of one class as a score

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, neural-network

I have a data set with three numerical inputs and two categorical outputs. Looks something like this:

[Data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN34W.png)
I'm trying to train a classifier to tell me what class it expects as an output, but more importantly what the likelihood for that class is.

Ultimately I'd like it to be able to consume three inputs [High, Medium, Low] and spit out one output

ie. 0.79  (which means 79% likelihood that the output would be 1)

I've been able to recreate the Iris example but all I get as an output is the class itself, but not the likelihood for the class.

I appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: Can you add some more details about the problem, add some code and replace the image?

Comment: Generally images are discouraged in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

[Softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) will give you probabilites out of the box. It's already implemented (I guess) in every DL package, i.e. tensorflow, torch ...

Using classical models it might be a bit tricky, as you're basically doing regression and must supply probabilites as your ground truth.

You might also consider different approach and learn distribution instead, optimizing KL metric. It's well covered [concept](https://blog.floydhub.com/n-shot-learning/) behind N-shot learning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the classifier output the likelihood of one class as a score.

As you know [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) is a function that takes as input a vector of K real numbers and normalizes it into a probability distribution consisting of K probabilities proportional to the exponentials of the input numbers.

So, instead of using `softmax` you can use [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) function which will return value monotonically increasing from **0 to 1**.

For example, here there are 2 classes so instead of getting probability distribution like 0.65 for one class and 0.35 for another, as it happens in case of `softmax`, you will get discrete values ranging from 0 to 1 for both the class in case of `sigmoid`.

Alternatively, you can also use [tanh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function) function which will scale the output value from **−1 to 1**.